# contextpath is appended

Tags: java, jsp, contextpath

i have created one hyperlink, and by clicking on that i am redirecting the page to another JSP, but i am not getting the correct URL that i am passing, URL is appended with another string and the page is not redirected,

please anybody have any idea about that, help me out

```
  <td align='<%=lstrColAlign%>' class="<%=tdclass%> Label2"  
   style="<%=rb.getDataStyleString(rvo,data)%>">
   <a  href="#" onclick="JavaScript:window.open( '<%=columnUrl%>','newwindow','top=0, left=0,   
             scrollbars=yes,status=1,resizable=yes,height= (screen.availHeight - 10),
             width= (screen.availWidth-5)')"> <%=rb.getDataValue(data)%></a>
   </font></td>
```

where i should get

```
...Project1-context-root/servlet/Reports.controller.ReportController?ActionFlag=get.............
```

but instead of that i am getting

```
...Project1-context-root/servlet/servlet/Reports.controller.ReportController?ActionFlag=get.....
```

so, extra word `servlet/` is appended

Comment: Can you put the code snippet here ?  so that people here could understand what is your problem ?

Comment: Plz post some sample code of what you are doing right now and what's the issue with your URL, so that people could understand your issue and get back to you....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative URL's without a leading slash are relative to the current context. I.e. if the current URL in the browser address bar is `http://example.com/context/index.jsp` and the relative URL to be opened from the current context is `context/page.jsp`, then the final URL would be `http://example.com/context/context/page.jsp`.

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Remove the same context in the relative URL, so that it ends as `page.jsp`.
2. Add a leading slash so that it becomes relative to the domain root: `/context/page.jsp`.
3. Make it an absolute URL instead: `http://example.com/context/page.jsp`.
4. Bring the context of the relative URL one step back: `../context/page.jsp`.

It works all the same way as with disk filesystem paths.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your <%=columnUrl> variable is getting

```
servlet/Reports.controller.ReportController?ActionFlag=get.....
```

And from your calling JSP, it's appending context path automatically..

Debug your columnUrl variable first and change that variable value to relative by updating it to ../context/page.jsp should works for you.